How to determine the elevation at the edges of a tilted rectangle?
The rectangle is slanted in direction B to C and the elevation at point B (between the edge and the floor) is 1.2 cm. C is the only edge that touches the floor. How to determine the elevation at points A and D?
P.S. My question has nothing to do with the chocolate bar, I just used it for an easier representation of the question. What originally prompted me to wonder about the elevation of the edges of a rectangle is a large format bathroom tile. I wondered how the elevation of the other two edges would get affected if I slanted it diagonally towards the drain.


You do realise that both numbers are dependent one of the other? Are you looking for a function, describing that relation?

Draw a horizontal at C and a vertical at D.  You get a right triangle and given the angle of rotation of the rectangle can use trig.

If $H$ is the projection of $A$ on $BC$, we have: $$CH={AC^2\over BC}\quad\text{and}\quad h_A=h_H=h_B{CH\over BC}=h_B{AC^2\over BC^2}.$$

Out of curiosity, why do you ask? And how much does that chocolate bar (?) weigh? (You might edit these answers into the question, for posterity!)

It weighs 100 grams but my question has nothing to do with the chocolate bar, I just used it for an easier representation of the question. What originally prompted me to wonder about the elevation of the edges of a rectangle is a large format bathroom tile. I wondered how the elevation of the other two edges would get affected if I slanted it diagonally towards the drain and hence my question.

Interesting! (I still think you should edit that back story into your question.) As some comments and the answer have pointed out, there's still a degree of freedom, which can be resolved by assuming equilibrium. However, if you're mounting the tile onto something, that resolution is not necessarily preferred.

Added it to the description. The tile gets mounted onto the bathroom floor which should be prepared/sloped down beforehand. Equilibrium of the edges would leave behind water pockets.

If the tile were expanded to a $120\mathrm cm$ x $120\mathrm cm$ square under the same conditions, the elevation at $B$ would be$$\frac{6}{5}\cdot 1.2=1.44\mathrm cm$$and for the tile to drain from $B$ to $C$ the elevation at $A$ and $D$ must be equal.
Since diagonal $CB$ of the square would be $120\sqrt 2$, the elevation at $A$ and $D$ would be$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot 1.44\approx 1\mathrm cm$$Thus since in the posted case rectangle length $CD=120\mathrm cm$, the height at $D\approx 1\mathrm cm$. But since width $CA=100\mathrm cm$, then the elevation at$$A=\frac{5}{6}\cdot 1\approx .83\mathrm cm$$
